# Can you change css code of a selected text input using JS

Tags: javascript, css

Let me be clear. I am asking how to change CSS code on a selected text. Not like a checkbox or anything of that sort.

```
            var txtarea = document.getElementById("txtarea");
            var selected = window.getSelection();
            if (selected) {
                //Change CSS Code
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which element do you want to change the CSS on?

Comment: What type of element are you selecting text in? If it's a `textarea` (as the id implies), you're out of luck. If it's a `div contenteditable`, then it's easier, and there are many questions with many answers about it.

Comment: Oh yeah I was using a text area

Comment: @Sam Gomena the element I wanted to change was the an input being selected

Comment: You can't style the text in a textarea, but could you give us more detail of what you want the user to be able to do/see in case there's a workaround we could help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a new styling using an **active class**, so you will be able to use it in every element with an ID of *txtarea* by clicking on the element you will toggle between the common *txtarea* and *txtarea active*

If you have an element, for example a textarea tag with an ID called *txtarea*

```js
document.querySelector('#txtarea').addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
```

Now you have to create a loop:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#txtarea").forEach(function () {
  this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
});
```

Now you have to create a function, so everytime you click on element it will add or remove the ID *active*:

```js
var ctrlAddItem = function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Comment: There should only be a single element with a given ID in a document. If you have more than one element with a given ID, you've got other problems in addition to the one asked in the question. Also, this doesn't answer the question of how to apply the styles to just the selected text in the element.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this:

```
var txtarea = document.getElementById("txtarea");

txtarea.style.width = '200px';
txtarea.style.height = '200px';
txtarea.style.color = 'grey';
txtarea.style.fontSize = '18px';
```

keep in mind that if the selected element doesn't exist in the DOM JavaScript will throw an error, so you don't need to use an if statement to test if it exists

Comment: This changes the style of all text in the `txtarea` element, not just the selected text. Changing just the selected text is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: all of this is styling an element, the text area accepts all this styling.

Comment: That is indeed what I said. The question put to you, though, was "How to change the CSS styles for just the selected text in the element?" **not** "How to change the CSS styles for the entire element?"